# Show all events that are active between two dates chosen from exposed date filter

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I have a problem in showing views results with an exposed date filter in D7 views 3.x.

**problem**

We have several events with a date field. It is required to fill in a start and end date.
We want a visitor to choose a start date and an end date with an exposed filter in a view.

*wanted results*

The results should show every event that occurs:

- Events that occur between the two dates
- Events that are already started. So the start
  date is already in the past.
- Events that are in the future but the end date is not between the chosen dates.

We have already tried to configure a startdate with "equals or greater than" and an end date with "equals or less than".

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your view to display all events that has start date >= x and end date <= x then what you have done show do the job.

In order to make it easy for others to help you, I recommend that you give description of your content types date fields, update your question with export ***code*** of your view so that others look and spot mistakes if any.

In the meantime, I have created a content type called event, and give it one field called i.e. date (I have configured the date field to collect both start date and end date - only year/month/day). I then setup a view and setup two exposed filters on start_date and end_date of this content type with operators as greator than or equal to and less than or equal to, and they seem to work without any problem. Follow is the export code of my view

```
    $view = new view();
$view->name = 'events';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Events';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Events';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['id'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['field'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'long',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
);
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'eventsbydate' => 'eventsbydate',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: date -  start date (field_date) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['id'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['field'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_date_value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['expose']['label'] = 'date (field_date)';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_date_value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['group_info']['label'] = 'date (field_date)';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['group_info']['identifier'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['group_info']['remember'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['group_info']['group_items'] = array(
  1 => array(),
  2 => array(),
  3 => array(),
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: date - end date (field_date:value2) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['id'] = 'field_date_value2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['field'] = 'field_date_value2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['operator'] = '<=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_date_value2_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['expose']['label'] = 'date - end date (field_date:value2)';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_date_value2_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_date_value2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'events';
```

screenshot of the configuration page is as follow 
[image]

If the above approach does not help you then have a look at this useful module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter

Comment: Hey Raf, thx for your answer. Still the module and your setup is not what i want completely. What i want is the combination from the between filter and your filters. Your view is the same view i have so that is a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like http://openwaterswimming.eu/eventslist ?
[image]
You can find the complete code at http://openwaterswimming.eu/files/code_eventlist.txt

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! May you show here the code? It is an important part of the answer which should not be lost for future readers. Stack Exchange doesn't aim to just help the OP, but any future reader with the same or similar problem.